# Android TalkBack : Read instructions after activity is rendered

Tags: android, android-activity, accessibility, screen-readers, talkback

Is there any way to force Talk Back to not just read the activity name, but also the text that says brief info about the content after the activity is rendered?
 Tried following in `onResume` but didnt work :

```
view.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED);
view.announceForAccessibility("Page description")
```

Can anyone tell me how i can get Talk Back to read a given text upon launch of activity without the user interaction?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @LoveForDroid No!